# Align multiple lines with columns in ggplot with dodged position

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot together columns and lines with `geom_col()` and `geom_line()`, using `position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")`, which would keep column width constant even if data is missing in some of the groups in x-axis.

```
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  count(clarity) %>%
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n) * 100) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = cut, y = perc, fill = clarity), position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
    geom_line(aes(x = cut, y = perc, color = clarity, group = clarity))
```

However, in the resulting plot lines do not match their corresponding columns as it can be seen:

[image: The plot combining missaligned columns and lines]

I've tried using `position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")` as well in `geom_line()`. But it does not work, just worsens the problem. What should I add in `geom_line()` to solve this problem?

Comment: My comment is out of scope but I am not sure the figure will be easy to read. How about displaying exclusively the lines through facet_wrap?

Comment: I second this comment. It is hard to imagine any useful overlay between a barplot and a line plot in this particular use case. I would either stick with the line or barplot. Moreover, there may be better alternatives, like with a [stacked barplot](https://r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2.html).

Comment: I actually intend to use this in a dataset with fewer groups and more column height differences. Thank you for your suggestions though, I will try both alternatives and compare them to my original idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... +
geom_line(aes(x = cut, y = perc, color = clarity, group = clarity),
          position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
          #0.9 being the default column/bar width
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that definitely worked. However, still had some trouble because the dataset I intended to use this on had some groups missing. Had to manually add them with zero values associated and really did the job.